# Celery tasks and task in group received but not executing

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery, worker

I'm working on an application designed to create a presentation based on screenshots created with selenium webdriver. Technology stack: `Python 3.8.6`, `Flask 1.1.2`, `Celery 4.4.7`, `Redis server 4.0.9` `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` .
When I add only one task the Celery worker works fine, but when i try to call 2 or 3 tasks one after another the tasks are received but never executed. The time of adding the task also affects the worker's behavior. When I add one task - waiting about ~ 2 seconds and then add second - all task are executed fine. But when i Try to add 3 tasks - always have problem. Sometimes first task is executed but others no but sometimes none of them are executed.
This is sample of my code:

**I'm running task by $.ajax - post:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/presentationTask/1234/4321',
    data: {
           filters_array: JSON.stringify([
               { filterTable : "Location", filterColumn: "City", filterValue: "Chicago, IL" }
    ])
    },
    success: function(data, status, request) {
        status_url = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
        update_progress(status_url, nanobar, div[0]);
    },
    error: function() {
       alert('Unexpected error');
    }
});
```

**Routing:**

```
@bp.route('/presentationTask/<workspaceId>/<reportId>', methods=['POST'])
def presentationTask(workspaceId,reportId):
    filters = request.form['filters_array']
    task = createPresentation.apply_async(args=[workspaceId,reportId,filters])  
    
return jsonify({}), 202, {'Location': url_for('tasks.taskstatus',
                                                  task_id= task.id)}
```

**And in method *"createPresntation"* I must call *"createScreen"* task many times so I used *"signature"* and *"group"* to run tasks in group. I'm waiting to all tasks are completed and then join their results by *"join() / join_native()"***

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def createPresentation(self, workspaceId, reportId, filterValues):
    self.update_state(state='PENDING')
    .
    .
    .
    
    for filter in json_filters:
        for page in json_pages["value"]:
            jobList.append(createScreen.signature(args=[workspaceId, reportId, page["Name"], 
                    filter['filterTable'], filter['filterColumn'], filter['filterValue'], currentIndex, 
                    page["displayName"]]))
   
    pageReportJob = group(jobList)
    results = pageReportJob.apply_async()

    while not results.ready():
        current = results.completed_count()
        
        self.update_state(
            state='PROGRESS',
            meta={'current': current, 'total': total,'status': message})  
        time.sleep(2)

    with allow_join_result():
        results.join_native()
    ....
```

**I'm running the celery worker by command:**

```
celery worker -A celery_worker.celery --loglevel=info --without-gossip 
--without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution - I installed Flower to monitor Celery tasks and I noticed that the celery allocates memory for the 2 main tasks (createPresentation) and waits for the (createScreen) tasks to be executed but they will never be executed because all CPUs/threads are occupied by tasks (createPresentation). So I created 2 queues one with high priority to createScreen and one default priority to createPresentation. Then i create celery routes and specify what routes is for each one.

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default'),
    Queue('priority_high'),
)

CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'app.screenshots.services.createScreen': {'queue': 'priority_high'},
    'app.presentation.services.createPresentation': {'queue': 'default'},
}
```